# How to validate presence of drop down list in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I want to know how to validate that a user selected a value.

My `collection_select` is:

```
= f.collection_select :person_id, @employee, :id, :fullName, {prompt: "Select employee"}, {class: "form-control"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use:

```
validates :person, :presence => true
```

This ensures that the selected `person_id` was not only present, but it also belongs to an existing `Person`.

Please note that if there are errors the errors will be added on `:person`, not on `person_id`. Depending on how you render validation errors you will have to check for error like this: `object.errors[:person]`.

When you want to present errors next to the `person_id` field, but cannot update your view, then you might want to use a [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) that checks `person`, but adds errors to `person_id`:

```
validate :person_existing

private
def person_existing
  errors.add(:person_id, :missing) if person.blank?
end
```

Comment: Do you know why validation don't display validation error. When I don't select anything and click create, nothing happen.

Comment: I use simple_form gem and it shows errors from other field but for collection_select doesn't react. I use object.errors.full_messages and this show error properly.

Comment: @ŁukaszKorol I updated my answer to address your question.

Answer (score 1):

For view tests in general, I would write a test against the returned HTML from the controller action. This gives the benefit of not doing in-browser tests (i.e. you don't have to use a web driver/headless browser), and since it's up to the individual browsers to render your HTML properly you can keep you tests simpler by just ensuring that the returned HTML from the controller action is correct.

If you want to validate that, when the user selects a given item, that it has been selected...well that's really up to the browser to do that job, so I don't know if you really want to test that. However, you should be able to check for the `selected` attribute on the tag ([see here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp))

That said, in general don't go too crazy with view tests, if this is indeed what you're going for. The view is the part of most apps that changes very frequently, and is quite fragile. You may find yourself chasing view changes a lot in your test suite.